# Setting picked image from UIImagePicker to UIImageView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to create code so that a user can set an image from their Library or from their Camera Roll and have it set to a ImageView on the screen.

I tried adding this function, however it doesn't seem to work

```
private func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        //You will get cropped image here..
        if let image = info[editedImage] as UIImage
        {
            self.Picture.image = image
        }
    }
```

Here is my code as of right now

```
class NewViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var Picture: UIImageView! //the image I am trying to change 

    let imagepicker = UIImagePickerController()

@IBAction func ImagePicker(_ sender: Any) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Photo", message: "Would you like to choose a picture from your libray, or take a new photo?", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .default, handler: { action in
            switch action.style{
            case .default:
                self.imagepicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                self.imagepicker.allowsEditing = true
                self.imagepicker.delegate = self
                self.present(self.imagepicker, animated: true)
                print("default")

            case .cancel:
                print("cancel")

            case .destructive:
                print("destructive")
            }}))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { action in
            switch action.style{
            case .default:
                self.imagepicker.sourceType = .camera
                self.imagepicker.allowsEditing = true
                self.imagepicker.delegate = self
                self.present(self.imagepicker, animated: true)

                print("default")

            case .cancel:
                print("cancel")

            case .destructive:
                print("destructive")
            }}))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? Can you describe exactly how it does not work? What is `editedImage`?

Comment: what I mean by "doesn't seem to work" is that when I select an image, the UIImage that I want to assign the chosen image to doesn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `method` signature as,

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    guard let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage else { return }
    self.Picture.image = image
}
```

You can check the method signature [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate/1619126-imagepickercontroller). Currently the method you have is not getting called by the `UIImagePickerController` delegate because of the wrong parameters. If you remove `private` keyword from the method, you will get a warning as below which means it looks like the same method but isn't what
`UIImagePickerController` delegate will call.

> Instance method
>   'imagePickerController(*:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)' nearly
>   matches optional requirement
>   'imagePickerController(*:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)' of protocol
>   'UIImagePickerControllerDelegate'

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to use `editedImage` as a key here? It should be `.editedImage`

Comment: because when I use `.editedImage` I get an error `Ambiguous subscript with base type '[String : Any]' and index type '_'`